# Render array of objects React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

My local JSON file is as follows

```
[
   { "time": "2017", "Id": 1, "value": 40 },
   { "time": "2018", "Id": 1, "value": 65 },
   { "time": "1018", "Id": 1, "value": 34 }
]
```

I imported the JSON like:

```
import * as readings from '../data/readings';
```

And I want to render my data in a list in a React component.

This is what I have been tried:

```
import * as readings from '../data/readings';

class Table extends Component {

  render (){

        const data = Object.keys(readings).map((row, index) =>
                    <li key={index}> {row} </li>);
        return (
              <div>
                <ul>
                  {data}
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

After rendering this component, I will see "default" on the screen but my aim is to have each object in one row like:

- "time": "2017", "Id": 1, "value": 40
- "time": "2018", "Id": 1, "value": 65
- "time": "1018", "Id": 1, "value": 34

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
I've read a lot of related question but I could not relate.

**Edit**:

My data is an array itself but the import gives it like an object. That's why I use **`Object.keys`** and not **`readings.map`**

Comment: Why are you using `Object.keys(readings)` ?

Comment: The data has already array format no need to use Object.keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readings` is itself an array so that is what you want to map over: `readings.map()`.  The items in it are the objects you want to display, so there is where you want to use `Object.keys()`.  Since you want to use the values as well, `Object.entries()` is slightly more readable.

Also, you are importing data from a JSON file so you should import the data as though it was a default export.  You should explicitly specify the `.json` file type since it is not a `.js` file.

```
import readings from '../data/readings.json';

class Table extends Component {

  render() {
    const data = readings.map((reading, index) => {
      const readingData = Object.entries(reading).map((k, v) => <span>{k}: {v}</span>);
      return <li>{readingData}</li>;
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {data}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Yes, readings itself is an array but it seems the `import` gives me an object. That's why I don't use `readings.map`

Comment: The fact that you are getting `default` as the rendered value suggests that you exported the JSON as a default export.  i.e. `export default [...JSON]`.  You are importing it as though it is a named export.  So you would want to import it accordingly.  I updated the import statement in my code.

Comment: Thank you but the readings.json is the one that I posted there is no `export default [...JSON]`. It's a file with an array of objects. I didn't export it.

Comment: In the case that it's a JSON file, the above method should work for you: `import readings from '../data/readings.json'`.  Worth noting that you should explicitly specify the file type since it is not a JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `readings` data is already an `Array`. You can directly use `map` on it.

```
import * as readings from '../data/readings';

class Table extends Component {

  render (){


      const readingsArray = Object.keys(readings).map(key => readings[key]);
      const data= readingsArray.map(obj => <li>{JSON.stringify(obj)}</li>);

        return (
              <div>
                <ul>
                  {data}
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: I can't because of  this error: `Attempted import error: 'map' is not exported from '../data/readings' (imported as 'readings').`

Comment: It looks like the `import` gives me an object

Answer (score 0):

Your `readings` is not an object, it's an array! So, what you should do is to iterate over it, and for every inside object, do the process of `Object.keys(readings).map()`

```
import * as readings from '../data/readings';

class Table extends Component {

  render (){

        const data = readings.map((row, index) => 
          <li key={index}>
            {
             Object.keys(row).map(e =>   
            `${e[0]: e[1],} `
            }
          )
          </li>
        )

        return (
              <div>
                <ul>
                  {data}
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
  }
}

export default Table;
```